# UiCollectionView bounces, but does't scroll to end

Tags: ipad

I have a collection view which I am creating to show a calendar. So one cell is my one day. I have enabled the scroll and bounce. But my collection view just bounces, but not scroll. I have set the collectionView frame height to 2500, which should be the height of the cell. 
Kindly help.

Comment: Why don't you add some code.

Comment: Some example of what you have done would be appreciated.